# How to get Text Appearance to work in Application Theme

Tags: android, styles

I know text appearance has been asked many times on here before, but I am having problems getting it to work correctly. Shown below is the theme xml as well as the text view style xml. The theme AppTheme is applied in the manifest file.

The problem I am having is the textview style is not being applied. I was expecting it to work in a similar way to android:buttonStyle.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Thank you

**Theme XML**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backgroundmain</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_main</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/textview_main</item>

</style>
```

**TextView Style XML**

```
<style name="textview_main">

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Snow</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply it through XML layout as below :

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:textAppearance="@style/textview_main"
    />
```

hope help you .

Comment: Hi, Kind of helps. However I am trying to apply it as a theme to the whole app rather than to each view.  Thanks